# Is there a way to assign whichever value is not missing in a list of variables to another variable in a quicker way?

Tags: sas

I am sitting with a situation and I can achieve the desired result but I was wondering if there is perhaps a quicker way to do it.

The long way would be something like this;

```
         if ^missing(X) and nmiss(Y,Z) = 2 then Value = X;
    else if ^missing(Y) and nmiss(X,Z) = 2 then Value = Y;
    else if ^missing(Z) and nmiss(X,Y) = 2 then Value = Z;
```

This is fine for a few variables, but what happens when you have a list of many more variables. Is there a way to assign whichever value is not missing in a list of variables to another variable in a quicker way?

Something like;

```
    if ^missing(in(X,Y,Z)) then Value = ^missing.value;
```

I know that the above code is incorrect, it is just a demonstration of my thought process.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if there is only one value that will ever be nonmissing, just add all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't *quite* what you describe, but see the `coalesce` function: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002518172.htm

```
value = coalesce(x, y, z);
```

This assigns the first non-missing value of `x`, `y` or `z` to `value`.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly like what you say you would do:

```
if n(of x y z) = 1 then value = coalesce(of x y z);
```

Of course you'd still have to assign values for non-n=1 values.

```
value = ifn(n(of x y z)=1,coalesce(of x y z), mean(of x y z));
```

Or something like that.  In that particular case the mean(of x y z) would be equivalent to coalesce(of x y z), but if your solution when multiple exist would not work with just one, then you can plug it in there.